# Prevent subclasses from overriding inherited functions in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, function, class, overriding

Is there a way to prevent subclasses from overriding inherited functions in Swift?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Take a look at the `final` keyword.

According to the documentation,

> You can prevent a method, property, or subscript from being overridden by marking it as *final*. Do this by writing the `final` modifier before the method, property, or subscript’s introducer keyword (such as `final var`, `final func`, `final class func`, and `final subscript`).
>
> Any attempt to override a final method, property, or subscript in a subclass is reported as a compile-time error. Methods, properties, or subscripts that you add to a class in an extension can also be marked as final within the extension’s definition.

You can find more information at the bottom of the [Inheritance section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH17-ID193) of the Swift Language Guide (look for the "Preventing Overrides" subsection).